# How to focus cursor on form element?

Tags: javascript

I want to add cursor after empty input into form element. Where first empty form are.
With this goal I tryed to add `this.focus();` into `validate()` function. But this wasn't succeeded.

And second point - how to set cursor after emerges page at brovser to first form element. I tryed with this target `onLoad();` method into `body`. But this wasn't succeeded.

**Code:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form with check</title>
            <script>
                function validate() {
                    if(document.form1.yourname.value.length < 1) {
                        alert("Enter your name, please");
                        this.focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                    if(document.form1.adress.value.length < 3) {
                        alert("Enter your adress, please");
                        this.focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                    if(document.form1.phone.value.length < 3) {
                        alert("Enter your phone number, please");
                        this.focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            </script>
    </head> 
        <body>
            <h1>Form with check</h1>
            <p>Input all data. When button Submit pushed data will be sent as message.</p>  
                <form name="form1" action="mailto:user@host.com" enctype="text/plain"
                onSubmit="validate();">
                    <p><b>Name:</b><input type="text" length="20" name="yourname">
                    </p>
                    <p><b>Adress:</b><input type="text" length="20" name="adress">
                    </p>
                    <p><b>Phone:</b><input type="text" length="20" name="phone">
                    </p>
                    <input type="SUBMIT" value="Submit">                    
            </form>
            onLoad();
        </body>    
</html>
```

**Question:**

- How to add this functionality to form?

Answer (score 1):

didn't you forget to do

```
onSubmit="return validate();" ?
```

Comment: Why needs to add this part - `"return ...`

Answer (score 1):

Replace `this.focus()` with `document.form1.yourname.focus();`

Here is the re-worked code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form with check</title>
            <script>
                function validate() {
                    if(document.form1.yourname.value.length < 1) {
                        alert("Enter your name, please");
                        document.form1.yourname.focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                    if(document.form1.adress.value.length < 3) {
                        alert("Enter your adress, please");
                       document.form1.adress.focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                    if(document.form1.phone.value.length < 3) {
                        alert("Enter your phone number, please");
                        document.form1.phone.focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                    document.getElementById("ff").submit();
                    return true;

                }
            </script>
    </head> 
        <body >
            <h1>Form with check</h1>
            <p>Input all data. When button Submit pushed data will be sent as message.</p>  
                <form id="ff" name="form1" action="mailto:user@host.com" enctype="text/plain"
                >
                    <p><b>Name:</b><input type="text" length="20" name="yourname">
                    </p>
                    <p><b>Adress:</b><input type="text" length="20" name="adress">
                    </p>
                    <p><b>Phone:</b><input type="text" length="20" name="phone">
                    </p>
                    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="validate();">                    
            </form>

        </body>    
</html>
```

And the Working [**DEMO too**](http://jsfiddle.net/MD7sp/)

Comment: Why needs to add this part - `document.getElementById("ff").submit();`

Comment: This is to submit the form. Also note that I have used <input type="button"> instead

Answer (score 0):

```
onSubmit="validate();"
```

In the context of your validate function `this` will be the global window object.

To handle the form in the function, based on your code, you can call it manually using `document.form1` or by id (or other selector), or you can send the form to the function:

```
  <script>
        function validate(sender) {
            if(sender.yourname.value.length < 1) {
                alert("Enter your name, please");
                sender.focus();
                return false;
            }
            if(sender.adress.value.length < 3) {
                alert("Enter your adress, please");
                sender.focus();
                return false;
            }
            if(sender.phone.value.length < 3) {
                alert("Enter your phone number, please");
                sender.focus();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    </script>
    <form name="form1" action="mailto:user@host.com" enctype="text/plain" onSubmit="validate(this);">
        <p>
           <b>Name:</b><input type="text" length="20" name="yourname">
        </p>
        <p>
           <b>Adress:</b><input type="text" length="20" name="adress">
        </p>
        <p>
           <b>Phone:</b><input type="text" length="20" name="phone">
        </p>
        <input type="SUBMIT" value="Submit">                    
   </form>
```